# Conditional display of properties for a WinForms UserControl?

Tags: winforms, dynamic, properties, user-controls, access-modifiers

I have a UserControl that does lookups.  The kind of lookup it does depends on a property called LookupType.  There are properties in the UserControl that are relevant for each LookupType.  So for example, LookupType = Vendor has properties like Vendor_RemitToAddr, while LookupType = ShipMeth has properties like ShipMeth_ShipMethID.

Intellisense and the Properties window show them all, which makes sense.  But I'd like to be able to have the UserControl only expose the properties that are relevant to the selected LookupType.

Is there any way to make the access modifiers on the properties change based on the LookupType property?

Note: this isn't an issue of functionality so much as it is of user experience.  The lookup works fine.  But it looks like a mess during development, and developer-users can set the wrong property by mistake.

Comment: You could try to implement a TypeConverter for your UserControl. Override the [GetProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.getproperties?view=net-5.0) method and apply an [`RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.refreshpropertiesattribute.-ctor?view=net-5.0) attribute to the `LookupType` property. That should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, Steeeve.  I'm trying to figure out how that would work.  I'm not sure what the GetProperties method is.  Is that the GetProperties in Reflection?  And the examples I've found of the RefreshProperties attribute also have an AttributeProvider.  Would I need that?

Comment: Intellisense will allways show all of the properties. I'll try to make a sample for the designer later, if you don't find a solution.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll post here if I manage to figure it out.

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible. For this you need to change the the `modifiers` property on your usercontrol, which can only be done with the designer. What you could do is assign some values to those properties you want hidden, and write some code in the setter that will refuse any other value as long this type is set. Not what you asked but it could stop someone from filling in a property that has no meaning with this lookuptype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simplified sample of a UserControl with only 3 properties: `LookupType`, `RemitToAddr` (only valid with LookupType.Vendor), `ShipMethID` (only valid with LookupType.ShipMeth). First, the `LookupControl`:

```
public enum LookupType
{
    Vendor,
    ShipMeth
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(LookupControlConverter))]
public partial class LookupControl : UserControl
{
    private LookupType lookupType;

    public LookupControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public LookupType LookupType
    {
        get => lookupType;
        set
        {
            lookupType = value;
            // Clear out unwanted property values
            switch (value)
            {
                case LookupType.Vendor:
                    ShipMethID = null;
                    break;
                case LookupType.ShipMeth:
                    RemitToAddr = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public string RemitToAddr { get; set; }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public string ShipMethID { get; set; }
}
```

The LookupControl contains some logic in the `LookupType`property setter to clear the values of the properties which don't make sense for the current LookupType. This makes sure that your control can't have inconsistent property values.
For the PropertyGrid in Windows Forms Designer I have implemented a `TypeConverter`:

```
internal sealed class LookupControlConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private readonly PropertyDescriptorCollection allProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(LookupControl), new[] { BrowsableAttribute.Yes });

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        if (context?.Instance is LookupControl)
            return true;
        return base.GetPropertiesSupported(context);
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        if (context.Instance is LookupControl control)
        {
            var propList = allProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToList();
            // Remove the unwanted property descriptors based on the current value of LookupType
            switch (control.LookupType)
            {
                case LookupType.Vendor:
                    propList.Remove(allProps[nameof(LookupControl.ShipMethID)]);
                    break;
                case LookupType.ShipMeth:
                    propList.Remove(allProps[nameof(LookupControl.RemitToAddr)]);
                    break;
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propList.ToArray(), true);
        }
        return allProps;
    }
}
```

Note: for the `LookupControlConverter` to take effect, you need to apply the `[TypeConverter(typeof(LookupControlConverter))]` attribute on the usercontrol and `[RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]` on the property
`LookupType`. The latter tells the designer that if the property changes, it should requery all the properties (not only the values). The TypeConverter delivers then the matching properties only.

For the IntelliSense in Visual Studio there is no solution, but if you implement the properties like shown above, at least you can keep the property values consistent.

And a last note: Visual Studio caches the controls used in the designer. So if you make changes, you'll probably need to clean the solution and restart VS for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like what I need.