# Changing the browsability of a property at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a PropertyGrid in my winforms application that displays the some of the selected object's properties. I want that a certain property will be sometimes displayed and somtimes won't, by my choice, (lets assume the the browsability changes every time a specific button is pressed at runtime).
Setting-up the browsability before runtime is pretty easy, using the BrowsableAttribute, from what I understand that attributes are set at design time hence I need another solution.
In many places I found this piece of code:

```
public static void ChangeBrowsability(SomeObject obj, string propertyName, bool isBrowsable)
{//usage: supposed to change browsability at runtime
        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)[propertyName];
        BrowsableAttribute attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
        FieldInfo browsableField = attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        browsableField.SetValue(attrib, isBrowsable);
}
```

The first problem is the `browsableField` is **always** null for some reason, and I would like to know why.
Also an alternative solution to this code may be welcomed.

Comment: Attribute information is stored in metadata and is compiles into the assembly at compile time

Comment: Duplicates: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321637/changing-browsable-attribute-at-runtime-c), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673101/how-do-you-control-what-is-visible-in-a-property-grid-at-runtime), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690481/conditional-browsable-attribute), etc...

Comment: You can implement a TypeConverter for your class and return whatever properties you want by overriding the GetProperties method. You don't have to use the BrowsableAttribute. You can get some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68941835/10318835).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the *reality* of how attributes are defined - they are baked into the IL; however, you *can* lie and cheat. The winforms `PropertyGrid` doesn't go directly to reflection - it uses an indirect route via `TypeDescriptor`, and `TypeDescriptor` *defaults* to using reflection. However, you can implement your own descriptor implementations that *change everything*, in particular (for this case): `PropertyDescriptor.IsBrowsable`. That's the good news.

The bad news that this is *hard*. Like; *really* hard; you'd have to *really, really* care about this feature to use it. It involves:

- capturing the outgoing reflection-based `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, so you can use it as a foundation
- implementing your own `ICustomTypeDescriptor` that exposes the properties as a "decorator"
- registering a `TypeDescriptionProvider` that exposes your own type descriptor
- capturing the outgoing reflection-based `PropertyDescriptorCollection` so you can use them as a foundation
- implementing your own decorators of the `PropertyDescriptor`s, forwarding most of the APIs, except for `IsBrowsable` where you would add your own logic

Doable, but: very complex and convoluted, and honestly: using APIs that are largely out of fashion and which haven't seen love in a decade. A worked example could easily run into the hundreds of lines of C#, so is beyond what I can reasonably supply here.

Comment: Thank you, so what is the alternaive?

Comment: @Mayerstro alternative: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes?view=windowsdesktop-5.0 - play with that, and specify *alternative* attributes that indicate browsability in different scenarios, and annotate your types accordingly

Comment: @Mayerstro I don't understand the question; can you clarify?